# Is there a way to get Selenium 2.23 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, ubuntu-11.10

I was using Firefox 12 with Selenium::WebDriver (ver 2.22) and everything was working fine.  Then I, stupidly, upgraded to Firefox 13 via the Ubuntu weekly updates.  Selenium (2.22) could not control FF 13 so I went out and got Selenium 2.23.  Then I started getting some weird behavior and thought it was my hard drive.

Stupid mistake number #2 I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 on my primary hard drive (thinking I was actually doing it to a backup drive but the backup only held backups of my scripts not an entire image of my primary).

So I installed Ubuntu 11.10 and I didn't think upgrading would be such a big deal (I believe I was using 11.04 previously but it might have been 10 something).  In the past upgrading Ubuntu versions has solved most issues for me not crated new ones.  Prior to 11.10 I used the command

```
sudo gem update --system
```

to upgrade all the gems and got Selenium 2.23 when I did it.  Now in 11.10 I get a message about update --system having been removed in Debian blah, blah, blah use apt-get.  However, apt-get leaves me with Selenium 2.22 not 2.23 and Selenium still can't control FF 13.

I tried guessing and used the command

```
sudo gem install selenium-webdriver-2.23.0
```

hoping to upgrade my selenium that way but no luck.

So after multiple attempts at getting Selenium 2.23 I downgraded FF to 12 and tested that FF 12 could be controlled via the IRB.  FF 12 immediately upgraded itself to FF 13.0.1 and now I'm back to square one.

Is there a way to get Selenium 2.23 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried downloading Selenium from the [official site](http://seleniumhq.org/)?

Comment: I have not.  The official site says 2.22 is still the latest for Ruby but I could swear I had 2.23.  There is a 2.23 for a standalone server (which I think I installed at one point to run a Selenium Grid that I never got around to finishing).  So maybe that was allowing me to do something I couldn't otherwise do.  Oddly enough I have another dev machine running Ubuntu 12.04 with Selenium 2.22 and FF 13 and all is well on it.  So at this point I've decided to just wipe the problematic machine and install Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 11.10 and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can install a specific version of Selenium using:

```
pip install selenium==2.23.0
```

To verify the version installed from pip, use (will list all installed libraries and their version number):

```
pip freeze
```

or to just list selenium:

```
pip freeze | grep selenium
```

Comment: Thanks for the info; I'm not familiar with pip.  The problem machine got upgraded to 12.04 which solved the issue (and several other minor ones).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to a stand alone selenium library (jar in my case) , that might help as you might be missing on updating the dependencies.